# Use a single thread with multiple objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, java-threads

So let's say I have a class which implements Runnable interface:

```
class Doctor implements Runnable{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    
    Doctor(String name, int id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public void run(){ /* some code */}
}
```

now class Doctor works as a thread, but how can I have one thread of Doctor class from multiple objects ?

for example:

```
Doctor d1 = new Doctor("George", 1);
Doctor d2 = new Doctor("Jim", 2);
```

How to start a single thread and know when `d1` or `d2` is running ?

If I run :

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(d1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(d2);
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

then here I create two threads and not one.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking here but it sounds like you want something like an executor service. You can submit Doctor tasks and they can run in turn on a single thread (if you configure a single thread executor). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: _now class Doctor works as a thread_: no, it doesn't. It implements `Runnable` which is helpful if you want to run it on separate threads. But nothing keeps you from writing `d1.run();` or `d2.run();` within your method.

Comment: @ThomasKläger yes, but I want to have a single thread for both `d1` and `d2`.. and `d1.run()`, `d2.run()` it executes run() of Doctor sequentially and not start the Doctor thread. I want it to start the thread, using two different Doctor objects, so I can pass their parameters, like d1.name to be different from d2's name variable.

Comment: I can only repeat: **Doctor is not a thread** and therefore you cannot start "the Doctor thread" - there is no such thing. You can either run them sequentially on a single thread or in parallel on two different threads (for example by creating two `Thread` objects), but you cannot "start the Doctor thread".

Comment: DO you want a centralized place where all doctors are stored together and working in parallel and you want to know which doctor is working?

Comment: @silentsudo yes